# Devolver un valor de una consulta MySQL encapsulada en una función

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

Estoy haciendo un backend con Express y necesito utilizar le módulo mysql para efectuar las consultas. El caso es que quiero realizar una función que me devuelva el id de la columna que tenga la referencia pasada como parámetro.
Tabla en mysql:
| idProduto    | Referencia|
| ------------ |-----------|
| 1            | 3R65Y     |
| 2      | 4T6D7      |
| ...     | ...      |

La función que quiero programar, `getIdFromRef(..)` se llamaría desde las diferentes rutas cuando se necesite saber la id de un producto con su referencia. El caso se describiría así:

```
router.get('/ex', (req, res) => {
  ...... getIdFromRef(req.body.referencia);
}

function getIdFromRef(ref){
   let response;
   db.query('SELECT `idProducto` FROM `ejemmplo` WHERE `referencia` = ?', [ref], function (error, results) {
        //manejo de errores .,..
        response = results[0].idProducto;
   })
   return response;
}
```

He indagado y creo que el problema es que al tratarse de una promesa, siempre retornará `undefined` porque la consulta todavía no se ha realizado y se realizará en el tiempo.
¿Como podría retornar el valor obtenido de la consulta para utilizarlo más adelante?

Comment: Si te retorna una promesa puedes trabajarlo con Async/await. Has la función async function f(){} y dentro de ella puedes crear una variable que coja el valor de la sentencia y ya tienes el valor para manejarlo como quieras, en el catch del try manejas el error. Por ejemplo, async function getIdFromRef(ref){ try{ let resultado = await db.query(); console.log(resultado); }catch(error){ console.log('ocurrio un error', error) }}

Answer (score 0):

Primero hacer notar un error que veo que tienes:

- Estas usando el req.**body**.referencia, lo que me llama la atención porque tu verbo es *get*. Si usas *get* procura usar req.**params**.referencia:

Dejando de lado esta observacion me avoco a tu duda.

El error está tal como lo indicas, te da `undefined` porque el `return` esta fuera de tu `db.query()`, con la aclaración de que un *callback* no es una promesa, si bien es *asincrono*, no son lo mismo. Ten en cuenta siendo esta función la que te trae los datos, pongas ahí un `res.send()` o en tu caso el `return` y siempre controlando los posibles errores que la consulta o la conexión pueda darte:

```
app.get('/ex/:referencia', (req, res) => {
    res.send(getIdFromRef(req.params.referencia));
})

function getIdFromRef(ref){
   db.query('SELECT `idProducto` FROM `ejemplo` WHERE `referencia` = ?', [ref], function (error, results) {
        //manejo de errores ...
        if (error) throw error;
        return (results[0].idProducto);
   });
}
```